# Android Studio get Null Pointer Exception error on adView.loadAd(adRequest) error. And crash on android lollipop device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I have been trying to add AdMob banner ad code to my app. When I try to do it I get Null Pointer Exception error on adView.loadAd(adRequest).

And another error is that my app crash on android lollipop os. How to fixed this. Hel Me. I am New in android.

This is my Layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <include android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" layout="@layout/ab"/>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main_f" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my main activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private ShareActionProvider mProvider;
    private long mLong;
    private Toast mToast;
    private AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_f);

        //Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //Maths Text View
        TextView mathsView = findViewById(R.id.maths);
        //Set Maths onClickListener
        mathsView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Step 2.2: Start the new activity
                Intent mathsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Maths.class);
                startActivity(mathsIntent);
            }
        });

        //Physics Text View
        TextView physicsView = findViewById(R.id.physics);
        //Set Physics onClickListener
        physicsView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Step 2.2: Start the new activity
                Intent physicsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Physics.class);
                startActivity(physicsIntent);
            }
        });

        //Chemistry Text View
        TextView chemistryView = findViewById(R.id.chemistry);
        //Set Chemistry onClickListener
        chemistryView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent chemistryIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Chemistry.class);
                startActivity(chemistryIntent);
            }
        });

        //Extra Text View
        TextView extraView = findViewById(R.id.extra);
        //Set Extra onClickListener
        extraView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent extraIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Extra.class);
                startActivity(extraIntent);

            }
        });

        //Premium Version
        Button pre = findViewById(R.id.btn_premium);
        pre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String appPackageName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // package name of the app
                try {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                }
            }
        });

        //Ads Initialize
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        //Google Banner Ads added
        adView = this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        //Google InterstitialAd Ads added
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.inst_ad));
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        //share the app
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        mProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
        setShareActionIntent("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    private void setShareActionIntent(String text) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        String str2 = text + getPackageName();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "All In One Formula");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, str2);
        mProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.rate_us) {
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + this.getPackageName())));
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + this.getPackageName())));
            }
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.about_us) {
            Intent extraIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(extraIntent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /**
     * Called before the activity is destroyed
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    //Double press to exit!
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (currentTime - mLong > 5000) {
            mToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.back_pressed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            mToast.show();
            mLong = currentTime;
        } else {
            if (mToast != null) mToast.cancel();
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Another activity code (Intent )

```
public class Maths extends AppCompatActivity {

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    //Set String value in adapter
    private final String[] n = new String[]{"Basic Algebra", "Indices", "Vector Addition and Subtraction", "Mathematical Properties",
            "Percentage Formulas", "Simple and Compound Interest", "Mensuration", "Binary Numbers", "Probability Formulas",
            "Celsius Formulas", "Angle Formulas", "Antiderivative", "Calculus Formulas", "Trigonometry Formulas", "Identities and Triangle"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maths);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        //Call final list with id
        //Call List View
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list_maths);

        //Google Ads added
        AdView adView = this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.inst_ad));
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        /*
         * Set the adapter In Maths class to showing list String
         * */
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_basic_learn, R.id.item_name_basiclist, this.n));
        //Enable Text clickable
        listView.setClickable(true);
        //Set OnItemClickListener to Maths layout
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //Transfer the data to all Maths sub class
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, BasicAlgebra.class));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, Indices.class));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, VectorAdditionMath.class));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, MathematicalProperties.class));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, PercentageFormula.class));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, SimpleandCompoundInterest.class));
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, Mensuration.class));
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, BinaryNumbers.class));
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, ProbabilityFormulas.class));
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, CelsiusFormula.class));
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, AngleFormula.class));
                        break;
                    case 11:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, Antiderivative.class));
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, CalculusFormula.class));
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, TrigonometryFormula.class));
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        Maths.this.startActivity(new Intent(Maths.this, Identities.class));
                        break;
                    default:
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Destroy the class when going back
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
        }
        finish();
    }

}
```

Can someone help me how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: you should first check if ad.isLoaded and if its loaded you can use ad.show() or something you want!

Comment: Post logcat please.

Comment: Here is my Logcat... https://pastebin.com/Eaq6cct2

Comment: Is there anyone to help me? Still, I stack in my code!!

Answer (score -1):

you can try with below link,
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);//sample to add AdRequest.

Thank you.

Comment: You might be not reading my post. I already did that. But not working!

Comment: Check your code according to the https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start